# Input:text jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('.search').click(function () {
    if ($('input:text').val().length == 0 ) { 
        $(".fill-out").fadeIn("1400")
    }
});

$('.search').click(function () {
    if ($('input:text').val().length >= 1) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

So I have some jquery that is supposed to show a hidden class called .fill-out when there is nothing in 1 or more text inputs when you click a submit button. I also am trying to say when the text length in the text inputs is greater than or equal to 1 then refresh the page once the button is pressed. The second part is not working correctly. It makes it so if any text inputs have text length greater than or equal to 1 then it refreshes the page. I want the first bit of code to still create the .fill-out portion. Can anyone help?

Comment: try `$('input[type="text"]').val().trim() == '')` - you should probably specify which textbox you're after as well, and if you need to validate more than one you could use a plugin like jQuery validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing only whether the first `input:text` element has a non empty value in it... you need to iterate through the list of input fields and check each of them to see whether its value is empty or not

You need to use

```
$('.search').click(function () {
    var valid = $('input:text').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length == 0
    }).length == 0
    if (valid) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    } else {
        $(".fill-out").fadeIn("1400")
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h22vw/)

Comment: For some reason on my page it is showing the .fill-out text when all of the input:texts have text in them but it works on you fiddle. Have any ideas?

Comment: I'm also using visual studios express 2012 to do this.